# The link does not open using Share plugin Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/share and also used the new plugin https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus to share the url link in my app to other socials. So now after sharing, when I click on the link from any socials, it does not open the web browser but just opens my app from the beginning.

I do not know what is causing this, can anyone please assist with my code:

```
  Widget _shareListItem() {
    return ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.black),
      title: const Text('Share'),
      onTap: () {
        Share.share("https://supersport.com");
      },
    );
  }
```

Where I am showing the modal with the link url

```
  void _presentBottomSheet() {
    final String slugfyTitle = slugify(article!.content!.title!);
    FirebaseAnalyticsService.logEvent('ss_overflow_select', {
      'content_type': 'ArticlePage',
      'sport': article?.categorisation?.sport![0].type,
    });
    showModalBottomSheet(
      useRootNavigator: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (builderContext) {
        return ModalBottomSheet(
          BottomSheetModel(
            shareUrl:
                'https://supersport.com',
            webViewController: _controller,
            quickFavourites: quickFavourites,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: `Share` discontinued you should use `share_plus` give it a try. 
 
https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Comment: Hi @Tuhin, I did try it using the new plugin share_plus and still it does not work.

Comment: Can I look into your code..? git Repo?

Will try my best to solve

Comment: Hi @Tuhin I cannot give you access to my repo because it is private. I can send you my code where I am using this. Please see my updated code in my post.

Comment: send it.. I'm also sharing a demo code... hope it will help

Comment: @Tuhin can you please send your demo code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252321/discussion-between-sadev-and-tuhin).

Answer (score 0):

add to your mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and on button pressed add this

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:(){
           if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                      // add the [https]
                      Share.share(
                          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepkart.team'); // new line
                    } else {
                      // add the [https]
                      Share.share(
                          "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sleepkart/id1602827809");
                      // new line
                    }
                    // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/settings');
        },
        
         //_incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), /
```

[image]

let me know its work or not

Comment: Hi @Tuhin, why only target android device and again are you trying to share url to different social? I can achieve that, the problem is when I click on the link after sharing, it does not take me to the browser.